# Combining LSTM along with Embedding layers in Keras

Tags: r, keras

I'm trying to design a network architecture that looks like this in R Keras:

```
Time Series data (LSTM) ---------------------\
                                              Concatenation ---> Output
Categorical variables (Embedding layers) ----/
```

All this to have a time series data augmented by few categorical variables. Here's my code:

```
library(keras)

# First embedding layer
input_1 <- layer_input(shape = 1)
input_1_embedding <- layer_embedding(input_1, 50, 5)

# Second embedding layer
input_2 <- layer_input(shape = 1)
input_2_embedding <- layer_embedding(input_2, 100, 10) 

# LSTM layer
lstm_input <- layer_input(batch_shape = c(32, 5, 1))
lstm <- layer_lstm(lstm_input, 5, stateful = TRUE)

# Concatenate both - the error happens here
outputs <- layer_concatenate(list(input_1_embedding, input_2_embedding, lstm)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model <- keras_model(inputs = list(input_1, input_2, lstm_input), outputs = outputs)
```

I'm getting the following error `A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1, 5), (None, 1, 10), (32, 5)]`.

As far as I understand, this comes from a fact, that I'm training LSTM on batches of size 32 and the embedding layers are not batched. I tried to introduce `batch_shape` into the embedding layers but this causes errors while training, as not all of the batches contain all embeddings.

I also tried to introduce batch shape after the embedding but with no luck so far. Is there any way to achieve mentioned network architecture?

Comment: "as not all of the batches contain all embeddings" what do you mean by this? Each training sample consists of two categorical variables plus a timeseries of 5 steps, right?

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for pointing at the questionable part of my post! I think I misunderstood how batches in embeddings works. I actually managed to make this work by setting `layer_input(batch_shape = c(32, 1)`.